# save Elements in Map/Array/Collection ...... Grails

Tags: arrays, grails, collections, groovy, dictionary

I'm new to `grails 1.3.7` and I have a problem.

I want to store different elements/paramters in one `list/array/map/`whatever..
the data to be stored looks like this:

`id : answera, answerb, answerc, answerd, answere, answerf, answerg, answerh`

`id` is a `number`

`answers` are `booleans`

so Ive got a lot of `ids` (well, maybe 20) and for each one 8 answers-booleans.
How do I store them the best, so that I can access them very easy again?

Thank you :-)

[EDIT] Thanks a lot for those answers, I will try it out now! :-)

I have now a map containing an id (int) and an object representing my answers (its a pojo which contains booleans answera, answerb, etc...)

Now I give this map to a gsp. How do I know get the data out of it? Thanks for help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

A Map would be the best approach, however it really has nothing to do with grails.  Do you need to persist these to a Domain Class/Database?

What a map would look like...

```
def map = [:]
map.put(id1, [new Answer(accepted:true), new Answer(accepted:false)]; 
map.put(id2, [new Answer(accepted:false), new Answer(accepted:false)];
```

I don't think this would give you an easy domain class to work with.  Sounds like you would want a grails domain class to encapsulate the answers.  Something like...

```
class Question{

    static hasMany = [answers:Answer]
    Integer id
    Boolean answered

    def hasBeenAnswered(){
        answers.each(){ answer->
            if (answer.accepted){
                answered = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    def acceptAnwser(Answer answer){

        answer.accepted = true;
        this.answered = true;

    }


}

class Answer{

    static belongsTo = [question:Question]

    Integer id
    Boolean accepted
    String text
}
```

And then your code would be easier to use...

```
def allQuestion = Question.list();
def allUnansweredQuestions = Question.findAllByAnswered(false);
def allAnsweredQuestions = Question.findAllByAnswered(true);
```

Comment: I dont need a domain object but thanks a lot for your help! I use your first snippet, it really helped me. I still have a problem: I dont know how to represent it now on a gsp, maybe you have an idea? Please take a look at my original posting, I updated it :-)

Comment: You should be able to use the <g:each in="${map.entrySet()}" var="entry">

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` seems like the obvious structure. The keys of the map should be the ids and the values of the Map should be either a `List<Boolean>` or (probably preferably) a class that encapsulates these 8 booleans.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did it like you said! I still have a problem: I dont know how to represent it now on a gsp, maybe you have an idea? Please take a look at my original posting, I updated it :-